# Doctrine 2 installation step by step

Tags: orm, doctrine, installation

This is my first time using doctrine 2. I need the ORM to handle my database.

I am having trouble understanding the "Getting Started" tutorial, and all other tutorials only explain how to install doctrine with a different framework. Whereas I only use plane php, I cannot find an understandable tutorial for someone with my beginner's background.

Where can I find a step-by-step tutorial about installing the doctrine 2 ORM and establishing a simple database connection to postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

Usually anyone using an ORM (like doctrine) prefer a framework also. In raw php I saw their github tests which is good. But [this](http://marco-pivetta.com/doctrine2-orm-tutorial/#1) is also good(please use keyboard left right button to navigate !!)

As for postgresql you can use its `pdo_pgsql` driver([reference](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#driver)). But if you used any framework you would have declared it there and no hassle in doctrine. I saw a pretty good tutorial in [this](http://joelverhagen.com/blog/2011/05/setting-up-codeigniter-2-with-doctrine-2-the-right-way/) one for codeigniter, its simple enough.